# Making duplicate of .pdf file using c++ code

Tags: visual-c++, networking

I am trying to write a code which should be able to make duplicate copy of a file in any format. At the moment, I'm trying it for .pdf format. Here is the code that I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream in("a.pdf", ios::binary);
if(in.fail())
{
    cout<<"\nThe file couldn't be opened\n";
    exit(0);
}

ofstream out("b.pdf", ios::binary);

while(!in.eof())
{
    char buf[1000];
    in.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
    out<<buf;
}
in.close();
out.close();
return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is that the duplicate file either gets corrupted or is smaller/larger than the original file. And also doesn't contain any text.
I am witting this code for my computer networks project in which I have to send a file in any format from server to client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this happens because you are using `operator<<` for output, which is designed to work with formatted strings, not binary data. [`std::ostream.write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) is the counter part of `read` meant to be used with binary/unformatted data.

```
while(!in.eof())
{
    char buf[1000];
    in.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
    out.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
}
```

`operator<<(char*)` probably stops on first "strange character". It also does not guarantee the output will be the same as input even in case of text, 'cause one can alter format output stream with formatting flags.

Actually I am not really sure what is the impact of `ios::binary` flag. Maybe you got confused that it would change behaviour of `operator<<` but it doesn't. I would expect it helps to alter buffering mode or something.

Comment: Yeah, it works perfectly fine after using out.write(buf, size(buf)); instead of out<<buf;
ios::binary reads the file as binary bits. Therefore, you can read and manipulate file in any format as I'll use it now to send to the client.